# Sum of a required value within two separate date range using Query function in Google sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-query-language

I am in need of a sum of a completed values present in between two separate dates using **Query** function. My sheets are as follows. The first sheet name is "Sheet1" & The 2nd sheet name is "Sheet2". I need the count(SUM) of **India completed** values in the cell Sheet2!A2 within the date range of Cell A1 & Cell A2. For this, I was trying with the below Query function. But it didn't work out. Can anyone please  help me here to get this data.

[image: Sheet1]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the below formula there

```
 =sum(query(Sheet1!$A$1:$D$13,"Select 1 where D='India' and A>=date '" & TEXT(A1,"yyyy-mm-dd") & "' and A<= date '" & TEXT(B1,"yyyy-mm-dd") &"'",1),0)
```

Comment: Hi Karpak, Thanks for your help. But when I am implementing this formula,  I getting a garbage value in return. Can you please help me why this is?

Comment: It is based on your selection, if you just want to count, instead of "select A, C, D" just use "Select 1"

Comment: urw, please mark this as correct answer if this addresses your query.

Comment: Karpak, Sorry to disturb you again.Can you please show me a way if I add a column next to D in sheet1 having the numeric data(i.e-5,8,9,4...) & need to find out the average keeping all the above conditions same.

Comment: try with this =AVERAGE(query(Sheet1!$A$1:$E$13,"Select E where D='India' and A>=date '" & TEXT(A1,"yyyy-mm-dd") & "' and A<= date '" & TEXT(B1,"yyyy-mm-dd") &"'",1),0)

Comment: Is it applicable for long sheets? my real sheet is having 57 columns. & this formula is giving O/P as "0" in return.

Comment: Based on number of columns you need to change the value here in "Sheet1!$A$1:$E$13"